# How can you find a variable length substring in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have several strings defined in a php script:

```
<?php
    $array = [
        'foobar',
        'helloworld',
        'applebanana'
    ];
?>
```

From those strings I've generated several substrings and put them into a database:

```
+-------------+---+
| id | substrings |
+----+------------+
| 1  | bar        |
| 2  | world      |
| 3  | banana     |
+----+------------+
```

I can't say how long each string/substring will be and I cannot use a delimiter. But I can say that the substring is always positioned to the very most right of the original.

So what I'd like to know is, how can I use the longer strings to find the shorter substrings of it in the database?

Note: I can't really use substring() or right() because I don't know the length of the substring in the database.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve (describing the process of your final algorithm on some sample data would help), but I believe you are looking for the [`CHAR_LENGTH()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length).

Comment: Post some sample data that should be searched and desired outcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given any string you have, you can still use `right` in conjunction with `lenght`:

`select * from substr_table where right('foobar', length(substrings)) = substrings`

However, this sounds like a terrible application design.

Comment: Well, what I'm doing is taking in an incoming request via php that contains any random domain, stripping it to the host using `parse_url()` and then deciding if this domain should have its sub domains stripped (by using the database) or if it should be remapped/converted into another domain completely. I came up with this solution and I didn't want to have to rely on delimiters, As far as I know, I think this is suitable for what I'm doing but if you or anyone can think of a better way then I'd love to know about it. +Cheers the query worked.